# Hilt - inject dependency from app to module

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

Lets say I have Android app project with one main "app" module and one "module1" module. "app" has dependency on "module1"

```
implementation project(":module1")
```

I'm starting to use Hilt to inject dependency from "app" to "module1".

In "module1" I define interface

```
interface TestInterface {
    fun doSomething()
}
```

which I implement in "app"

```
class Test: TestInterface {
    override fun doSomething() {
        Log.i("Test", "Something")
    }
}
```

Now, I want to inject "Test" implementation into "module1" and use it.
I created test class:

```
class Work {

    @Inject
    lateinit var test: TestInterface

    fun doWork() {
        test.doSomething()
    }

}
```

Which I try to use in MainActivty

```
Work().doWork()
```

But it does not work.

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property test has not been initialized
    at module1.Work.getTest(Work.kt:8)
    at module1.Work.doWork(Work.kt:11)
```

I've set:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity
```

and

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class HiltApplication
```

Hilt module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface Dependencies {
    @Binds
    fun bindsTestInterface(test: Test): TestInterface
}
```

Any idea why this does not work?

Comment: You are actually injecting `TestInterface` non android entrypoint class. Work is not an entrypoint andrid class here. You can inject this in activity, fragment, service etc

Comment: You can use constructor or provides injection to inject in Work class

Comment: Can you give me an example? I tried to use @Provides but that didn't work too.

Comment: I managed to find an example, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution in case someone needs it.

MainActivity

```
@Inject
lateinit var work: Work
```

Hilt module

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object Dependencies {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun bindsTestInterface(): TestInterface {
        return Test()
    }
}
```

Work

```
class Work @Inject constructor() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var test: TestInterface

    fun doWork() {
        test.doSomething()
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello @Ivan Škugor, could you please help me with my issue? I think it's very similar to yours, and I'm stuck.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73089553/android-kotlin-hilt-multi-module-app-cannot-access-application-class-from